# Currency Error keeps giving me the value of "C"

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to coding on Visual Basic and was wondering if anyone knew why the end total cost isn't working. Currently I keep getting C as the end value

Here is the variables bit so you can see the data types I have set

```
Dim Height As Decimal
Dim HeightValidation As Boolean
Dim Width As Decimal
Dim WidthValidation As Boolean
Dim TotalArea As Decimal
Dim Paint As String
Dim PaintValidation As Boolean
Dim Cost As Decimal
Dim FinalCost As Decimal
Dim UndercoatValidation As Boolean
Dim Undercoat As String
```

And here is the last bit of the code

```
Do Until UndercoatValidation = True
    UnderCoat = InputBox("Would you like to add an Undercoat to your purchase?")
    If Undercoat = "Yes" Then
        FinalCost = Cost + (TotalArea * 0.5)
        UndercoatValidation = True
    ElseIf Undercoat = "No" Then
        FinalCost = Cost
    Else
        UndercoatValidation = False
    End If
Loop
MsgBox("Thank you for using the Paint Calculator")
MsgBox("Your total cost is"(FormatCurrency(FinalCost)))
```

Thanks in advance. By the way before I added the currency bit it worked.
So the values of cost will change depending on whether or not the user wishes to have an undercoat, what type of paint they use and the area of the room.

```
Do Until HeightValidation = True
    Height = InputBox("Enter the height of the room you are working in: ") 'Gains users value
    If (2 <= Height) AndAlso (Height <= 6) Then 'Only allows number between 2 and 6
        HeightValidation = True 'breaks the loop if the requirements are met
    Else
        HeightValidation = False 'continues the loop if the requirements are not met
    End If
Loop

Do Until WidthValidation = True
    Width = InputBox("Enter the width of the room you are working in: ") 'Gains users value
    If (1 <= Width) AndAlso (Width <= 25) Then 'Only allows number between 1 and 25
        WidthValidation = True 'breaks the loop if the requirements are met
    Else
        WidthValidation = False 'continues the loop if the requirements are not met
    End If
Loop

TotalArea = Height * Width

Do Until PaintValidation = True
    MsgBox("There are 3 different types of paint you could you, which are: Luxury which costs £1.75 per square metre; standard which costs £1 per square metre and economy which costs £0.45 per square metre")
    Paint = InputBox("Which type of paint will you be using to paint the walls?")
    If Paint = "standard" Then
        Cost = TotalArea * 1
        PaintValidation = True
    ElseIf Paint = "economy" Then
        Cost = TotalArea * 0.45
        PaintValidation = True
    ElseIf Paint = "luxury" Then
        Cost = TotalArea * 1.75
        PaintValidation = True
    Else
        PaintValidation = False
    End If
Loop
```

That's the rest of the code that works out the costs, sorry for all the code not being annotated.

Comment: What are the values of `Cost` and `TotalArea`? Also, I would recommend not using a Do/Loop with an InputBox. There's no need to have the user type Yes or No...if they type it lowercase, your logic fails. Just use a MessageBox with Yes and No buttons and do your logic based on the return value.

Comment: The values of cost and total area will change depending on what the user enters. If needed i can upload that bit of the code. And with the logic thing I will improve my code to be like how you said. Sorry still new to vb

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> MsgBox("Your total cost is"(FormatCurrency(FinalCost)))
> ```

That means "show the [character at position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) `FormatCurrency(FinalCost)` from the string `"Your total cost is"`.

Apparently the result of `FormatCurrency(FinalCost)` is implicitly convertible to `11`, so it shows the `"c"`.

Apparently you meant

```
MsgBox("Your total cost is " & FormatCurrency(FinalCost))
```

Please use `Option Strict On` to not have this kind of problems in the future.